# Multiple ComboBox on DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` on a Winforms `DataGridView` and I would like to have 2 `ComboBox` on the same `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. I want to be able to choose 2 different values for each cell, having different `DataSource` for each `ComboBox`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not have it as two columns ?

Comment: I have 30 columns, one for each day of the month and need to save 2 values for each day. If I do that I wiil have to double the amount of columns that is already big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible but not worth to...
Why don't you just use 2 common combobox column.

If you have to do this, i think you need:
- write a container user control which hosts 2 comboboxes.
- Customize a datagridviewcolumn to host your control.

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9238/WinForms-Custom-Container-Control

Comment: I did not know about custom DataGridviewColumns. I guess that's the ony way to do although it is quite hard work. Thanks!